# Application force closing with NullPointerException in logcat

Tags: java, android, root

No errors in eclipse.. But whenever I start the application it FC's :(
I am trying to make a app which install scripts to init.d whenever I press the button. I think the problem is the brackets cuz they troubled me ALOT! You can see that they are arranged in an unorganised manner.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.kernel.version;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.stericson.RootTools.Command;
import com.stericson.RootTools.RootTools;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {



        RootTools.remount("/system/", "rw");
        Command command = new Command(0, "su", "cp /sdcard/scripts/* /system/etc/init.d/")
        {
                @Override
                public void output(int id, String line)
                {

                }
        };
        try {
            RootTools.getShell(true).add(command).waitForFinish();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            }
        });}}
```

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="141dp"
        android:text="Install Scripts" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: _App force Closing without errors_.? Are you sure you are working on Android.?

Comment: snapshot your logcat ..!

Comment: here is the logcat sir
http://pastebin.com/nXMqu9gM

Answer (score 2):

I think **NullPointerException** on Line, `button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`

Because You missed `setContentView(R.layout.Activity_main);` before accessing Button from layout Xml file.. So your `Button button` is **NULL**.

Something Like,

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // You missed this code line,
        setContentView(R.layout.Activity_main);

        Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Comment: oh my god! how can i miss that one!! Thanks alot!! As usual the people here are geeks and very useful!!!

Answer (score -1):

First create Button instance then add listener
Button button;

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    }
}
```